# Complete song master and mixing tutorial

Tags: logic-pro

I hope this is not offtopic. I need a video tutorial for complete song production specially for logic studio. If you can't find specially for logic studio, for any other audio editor is fine also. Goal is to record one song with few instruments and learn to make complete mixing and mastering.

Comment: just hit record for four minutes and thirty three seconds, and you are done! License fees to be paid to the estate of John Cage. But seriously, this is a really big topic. Can you narrow your question down somewhat?

Comment: Or, record for 4:52, call it a track _inspired~ by John Cage, and don't pay license fees. I think that extra page of rests in the sheet music would make it significantly different enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&q=logic%20studio%20video%20tutorial&oq=logic%20studio%20video%20tutorial&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l4.306909.306909.0.312429.1.1.0.0.0.0.841.841.6-1.1.0...0.0.vjBOc_3Fyrw) has Apple's site, where [this link](http://www.apple.com/logicpro/how-to/) is described as "Watch video tutorials that show you how to compose, record, mix, and perform with ... " as it's first result. That pretty much sounds like what you need.

However, from Stack's FAQs, [this link](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) includes, as its first point,

> **Do your homework**
>
> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your
>   question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
>   and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
>   the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
>   answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant
>   answer!

Your reputation score tells me you're a little green, but seriously--check out the FAQ. You'll get better results with your questions if you understand the expectations. Just sayin'.

Comment: it's not mastering specific stuff in there.. and it's unprofessional advices at all i've found one for cubase a complete course probably that will do, im searching FOR SERIOUS video school not crappy apple tutors.

Comment: @holms ...and that's a perfect example of "tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs" e.g., including a line about "i looked at apple's stuff <here>, and I really need something more in depth on mastering techniques". I knwo when I first started asking questions, it took me a while to get into the habit of presenting my research, but I can tell you that the quality of the answers improved exponentially. Good luck!